# find the sum of squares and cubes from 1 to 10

Tags: java, sum

I'm new to Java and i'm trying to find the sum of squares and cubes from 1 to 10. But i only know how to find the sum from 1 to 10, i think they're kind of similar but i'm having trouble figure it out.

```
public class sumNumber {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        final int LIMIT = 10;

        System.out.println("The sum of the numbers from 1 to " + LIMIT + " is " + sumNumber(LIMIT));
    }

    public static int sumNumber (int number) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i=1 ; i <= number ; i++) {
            sum += i;
        }

        return sum;
    }
}
```

Comment: `sum += i * i;` for the squares. I'm guessing you know how to do cubes now.

Comment: Instead of `i` you need `i * i` to get the square of `i`

Answer (score 1):

I propose this code :

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
var sum = arr.map(x => x*x*x).reduce((a,b) => a+b);
console.log(sum); // 3025
```

And if you want a more generic ES6 function :

```
var sumCube = n => Array(n).fill(0).map((x, i) => Math.pow((i+1),3)).reduce((a,b) => a+b);
console.log(sumCube(10)); // 3025
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out this code for squares :

```
public static int sumNumber (int number) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i=1 ; i <= number ; i++) {
        sum += Math.pow(i,2);
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Do `Math.pow(i,3)` for cubes.

Answer (score 0):

You add one more parameter to reuse the code like type

```
public static int CalculateNumber (int limit,string type) 
{   
    int result=0;
    switch(type)
    { 
        case "sum":
        for (int i=1 ; i < = limit ; i++) 
        {
            result += i;
        }
        break;

        case "square":
        for (int i=1 ; i < = limit ; i++) 
        {
            result += i*i;
        }
        break;

        case "cube":
        for (int i=1 ; i < = limit ; i++) 
        {
            result += i*i*i;
        }
        break;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8+, you could use an `IntStream` to `range` between `1` and `LIMIT`, performing map operations to get the sums. Something like,

```
int sum = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, LIMIT).sum();
int sum2 = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, LIMIT).map(x -> x * x).sum();
int sum3 = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, LIMIT).map(x -> x * x * x).sum();
```